# Find the reason of why does Sunfire V100 (SunOS 5.9) server not start

Tags: solaris, boot, lom

I have a Sunfire V100 (SunOS 5.9) server which was working fine till 14th February 2014. After that day we can not access this server. Today I was able to connect server through a console and I got the following message on the hyper terminal of a windows XP PC. Please find the attached screenshot of the hyper terminal on the following link.

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7mhJdZLGeVNQUloaTNrdExXSFE/edit?usp=sharing]

I have also a different Sunfire V100 (SunOS 5.9) server with same configuration say server B. I started server B using the poweron command in the LOM prompt. After booting process it showed many details like host name and asked for console login and I logged in successfully when I started the faulty server say server A. It got stuck after showing the message according to attached screenshot. So i conclude that the reason for this issue is server is not booting successfully. Please help me with the possible solution. Thanks in advance and thanks Michael Hampton for posting the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some memory fault which did not reappear again after restarting the server after 2- 3 days and it worked fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty old box. There's a good chance it had a catastrophic hardware failure. Given how horrid the hardware architecture of the V100 is, I don't think I'd bother trying to fix it; I'd upgrade to a newer box. A used V210 would be a big improvement, and wouldn't quite feel so much like throwing money down the drain.

That said, you might pop the thing open, take out the hard drive, and see if you can get it to spin up and perform basic diagnostics on some other box. (If you don't already have a USB to IDE/SATA adapter in your toolbox, go get one; it's indispensible.) It wouldn't be surprising if the disk is dead. The V100 uses ATA-2 disks and has a 28-bit LBA limit, so it can't use more than 137GB of space per physical disk. You can stick a 160GB UltraATA-100 disk in there, but you'll be wasting 23 GB and you won't get any extra speed. With used V210s running $120–$300 on the open market, spending $80 for a new WD 160GB disk to resurrect a V100 just seems like a waste.

The V100's IDE implementation is really poor; I've seen boot problems from having two internal IDE disks where neither one was quite "dead" by itself, but two of them in the same V100 caused the V100's IDE bus to give up. If you've got two internal disks, try disconnecting one at a time and see if that helps.